# Create buckets in snowflake without specified max value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, histogram, bucket

At the moment I'm using this in my query to get order value bins:

```
   case 
 when (oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity) >= 0 and (oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity) <= 10000 then '0-10000'
 when (oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity) >10000 and (oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity) <= 20000 then '10001-20000'
 when (oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity) >20000 and (oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity) <= 30000 then '20001-30000'
 when (oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity) >30000 and (oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity) <= 40000 then '30001-40000'
 when (oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity) >40000 and (oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity) <=50000 then '40001-50000'
 when (oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity) >50000 then 'over 50000'
     end as orderVolumeBins
```

Instead I want to use this function:

```
WIDTH_BUCKET( <expr> , <min_value> , <max_value> , <num_buckets> )
```

Which in my case could be

```
WIDTH_BUCKET( <volumeBins> , <0> , <50000> , <5> )
```

But that wouldn't give me the bin with all orders that have volumes above 50000. Does anyone know if there's a variant where this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But that wouldn't give me the bin with all orders that have volumes above 50000

[WIDTH_BUCKET](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/width_bucket.html):

> When an expression falls outside the range, the function returns:
>
> - 0 if the expression is less than min_value.
> - **num_buckets + 1 if the expression is greater than or equal to max_value.**

For 50,001:

```
SELECT WIDTH_BUCKET( 50001 , 0 , 50000 , 5 )
-- 6
```

EDIT:

> Can I name the bins in any way? Now I'm getting 1,2,3,4,5,6 instead of 10k-20k etc

```
SELECT
   CASE WIDTH_BUCKET((oi.pricePerItemExVat * oia.quantity), 0, 50000,5)
     WHEN 1 THEN '0-10000'
     WHEN 2 THEN '10001-20000'
     -- ...
     WHEN 5 THEN ...
     WHEN 6 THEN '>=50000'
   END
```

Comment: Is there anyway to extract the naming of the buckets programmatically vs hardcoding the values ? For example, if we knew the min and the max of each bucket we can then construct the name.

Comment: @SriK You could construct the output string `CONCAT(WIDTH(...) * ... + ,'-', WIDTH(...) * ... +)`

Comment: something like - FLOOR(lower_bound + (upper_bound - lower_bound) * (WIDTH_BUCKET(col, lower_bound, upper_bound, num_buckets) - 1) / num_buckets) ? This came from ChatGPT btw when i gave it this same question

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this, maybe not the neatest solution but it did actually work for me. Here is an example I think is a little easier to understand, and this worked for me on Snowflake.

```
    SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WIDTH_BUCKET(num_days, 0, 49, 7) = 1 THEN 1 END) AS "Week 1",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WIDTH_BUCKET(num_days, 0, 49, 7) = 2 THEN 1 END) AS "Week 2",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WIDTH_BUCKET(num_days, 0, 49, 7) = 3 THEN 1 END) AS "Week 3",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WIDTH_BUCKET(num_days, 0, 49, 7) = 4 THEN 1 END) AS "Week 4",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WIDTH_BUCKET(num_days, 0, 49, 7) = 5 THEN 1 END) AS "Week 5",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WIDTH_BUCKET(num_days, 0, 49, 7) = 6 THEN 1 END) AS "Longer than 5 weeks"
    FROM your_cte
```